# IOS Swift : UIPanGestureRecognizer on 2 differents views

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm very new in swift/xcode and i have a problem with UIPanGestureRecognizer.
I'm trying to do a sliding menu who slide when you "pan" him.
The sliding menu is working well, and i can slide it by panning the menu (UIViews).
But this menu have to be hidden at the beginning.
So I put a little arrow bellow it. Here is the problem... I want had a UIpanGestureRecognizer who did the same action of the previous one. When i'm panning the arrow, of course.
So, here is the code who works :

```
// all is working with this code. handlePan is working well.
var panGestureRecognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer!
panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handlePan:")
self.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)
```

And this is what i have try for the arrow:

```
let mysubView = UIView()
let arrowView = UIImageView()
let imageName = "arrow"
let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)

var panGestureRecognizerArrow:UIPanGestureRecognizer!


//put subview bellow the menu
mysubView.frame = CGRect(x: self.bounds.size.width / 2 - 15, y: self.bounds.height, width: 30, height: 30)
//put arrow bellow the menu
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: self.bounds.size.width / 2 - 5, y: self.bounds.height, width: 10, height: 10)

addSubview(imageView)
//put a invisible subview over image, to have a bigger "hit box"
addSubview(mysubView)

//I think the problem is HERE
panGestureRecognizerArrow = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: mysubView, action: "handlePan:")
self.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizerArrow)
//it did'nt passed by the handlePan function when I pan mysubView. There is debug console out in it.
```

Like said commentary, i think the problem is in the last two line.
Someone know what's wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

You should attach `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to the `mysubView`:

```
panGestureRecognizerArrow = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handlePan:")
mysubView.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizerArrow)
```

For panning gestures that start near an edge of the screen you can use [UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer) as well.

Comment: thank you, but it still didn't work.
I change it to a UITapGestureRecognizer.
tapGestureRecognizerArrow = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "snapToBottomTap:")

I create snapToBottomTap function to try. it works if I add the gestureRecognizer to self. But nothing works if I try to add it to another view. I write only in the "MenuView" class.
Did I need to create a class for the subview or something ?

Comment: As far as I remember `UIGestureRecognizer` doesn't work if alpha is 0. That is why I would propose you to handle touches in the main view and move image + menu according to the translation (`CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];`).